# How can I get  pic_squre and sex from user id's I already have

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am creating an application in which user can select 10 friends of the user to tag.

I can get those selected 10 friends uids into an array, like:

```
xyz[0]=1234567
xyz[1]=5364753
```

What is the FQL query to select `pic_squarw` and uid where the user id is id in the array, `xyz[]`.

Answer (score 0):

$data->sex http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

cropped picture http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture