# Select uid, sex, and pic square from the 10 selected friends of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get pic_squre and sex from user id's I already have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786618)

I want to select uid, sex, pic square from the 10 selected friends of a user.

And those 10 friends are selected by the user, and I can store their uid in a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) array, say

```
$xyz[]
```

So how can I use that array to get the uid, sex, and pic square of those 10 friends by [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language)?

And if this is not possible with FQL, how I can do it with other methods?

I tried this

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid,sex,pic_square FROM friend WHERE uid in (" . implode(",", $xyz) . ");';
```

But this is not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/`. You can execute FQL queries here.

So `friend table` has only two columns: uid1, uid2 as stated in `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/`

Finally your query should be:

```
SELECT uid, sex,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in(  select uid2 from friend where uid1=786644124)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "friend" with **"user"**

```
$FQLQuery = 'SELECT uid,sex,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (" . implode(",", $xyz) . ");'
```